# Why is it advised to increase exercise gradually not drastically?

Tags: exercise, push-ups

I do exercise everyday especially the pushups but it is often advised to me that I should increase my pushups count gradually not drastically like increasing it by 1 everyday. But why can't I do it drastically? What's the scientific reason behind it?

Answer (score 2):

Physical and mental burnout, generally. If you increase your exercise too rapidly, there's a greater chance of causing yourself injury that will keep you from being able to exercise. And even if you avoid actual injury, waking up the next morning feeling extremely tired and sore, and barely able to move, is often a demotivator to keep exercising.

Making sure to take your rest days helps, but also, it's a good idea to not push yourself too hard, for fear of losing everything.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to push ups, you're moving a relatively low amount of weight as it is only a fraction of your body weight that you are pressing and therefore going until failure may tire you out but won't likely cause any damage or injury. That advice is more applicable when talking about bench press as novices are prone to being overconfident and lifting too heavy which can cause serious injuries. Even incrementally increasing the weight too fast can also cause injuries because your tendons and ligaments do not strengthen as quick as your muscles do. This is why bodybuilders who are on steroids can tear ligaments and tendon, often in the biceps or chest. This is because their muscles get stronger much faster than the tendons do and although they can lift the weight the tendons cannot keep up with the resistance.

Comment: When trying to increase your strength at any exercise its ideal, at least as a beginner,  To train at roughly 80% to 85% of your RPE ( Rate of Perceived Exertion). This means if you push to the absolute Max and can only remarks and can only do 10 push-ups, do a few workouts doing 3-5 sets of 8 push ups (80%). Then, test your Max again, and redo the process at the new 85%